# in R, data.frame() or write.csv2() functions, change the encoding

Tags: r, dataframe, text, encoding, character-encoding

I have a text in Persian:
`tabs <- "سرگرمی"` 
 and I need to have it in dataframe. 
 when I try:
 `final <- data.frame(tabs)`

I get this:

[image]

exporting the text to .csv using write.csv2(), gives me the same problem too.

any idea how to have the text as original encoding?

Comment: can you check your locale setting

Comment: @akrun
thanks, it worked:
Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL","Persian")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can set the locale with `Sys.setlocale`

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL","Persian")
```